# What is 'Live Offers' and 'Additional Locations' in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Marketing Cloud order forms I see couple of line items, for which there are no documentations online. Although the costs are not high, I am not clear what is the use of those. That includes

1. Additional Locations
2. Live Offers

What are they used for?

Comment: I see this and many of your previous questions have good answers, which you haven’t marked as accepted. Accepting answers is a good indicator for others in search of similar solutions, and gives credits to members of this community who volunteer to share their knowledge. Please go through your previous questions, and mark answers as accepted where they provide good replies to your enquiries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Offers was a feature with open-time offer targeting (QR codes, coupon codes, etc.), however it got removed from SFMC in 2019. [Here is the info](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000380604&type=1) about the retirement.

When it comes to "additional locations", I assume it is an add-on to Mobile Push, allowing you to create additional locations for geofencing, in addition to the number of locations available ootb in your edition.

Your Salesforce Account Executive will be able to provide you with the right answer here.